# MAX Date of multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting

How do you return 1 value per row of the max of several columns:

TableName [RefNumber, FirstVisitedDate, SecondVisitedDate, RecoveryDate, ActionDate]

I want MaxDate of (FirstVisitedDate, SecondVisitedDate, RecoveryDate, ActionDate) these dates for all rows in single column and I want another new column(Acion) depends on Max date column for ex: if Max date is from FirstVisitedDate then it will be 'FirstVisited' or if Max date is from SecondVisitedDate then it will be 'SecondVisited'...

The Total result Like:

Select RefNumber, Maxdate, Action From Table
group by RefNumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a custom function to do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MaxOf5]
(
    @D1 DateTime,
    @D2 DateTime,
    @D3 DateTime,
    @D4 DateTime,
    @D5 DateTime
)
RETURNS DateTime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result DateTime

    SET @Result = COALESCE(@D1, @D2, @D3, @D4, @D5)

    IF @D2 IS NOT NULL AND @D2 > @Result SET @Result = @D2
    IF @D3 IS NOT NULL AND @D3 > @Result SET @Result = @D3
    IF @D4 IS NOT NULL AND @D4 > @Result SET @Result = @D4
    IF @D5 IS NOT NULL AND @D5 > @Result SET @Result = @D5

    RETURN @Result
END
```

To call this, and calculated your `Action` column, this should work:

```
SELECT
    MaxDate,
    CASE WHEN MaxDate = FirstVisitedDate THEN 'FirstVisited'
       WHEN MaxDate = SecondVisitedDate THEN 'SecondVisited'
       WHEN MaxDate = RecoveryDate THEN 'Recovery'
       WHEN MaxDate = ActionDate THEN 'Action'
    END AS [Action]
FROM (
    SELECT
       RefNumber,
       dbo.MaxOf5(FirstVisitedDate, SecondVisitedDate, RecoveryDate, ActionDate) AS MaxDate,
       FirstVisitedDate, SecondVisitedDate, RecoveryDate, ActionDate
    FROM table
) AS data
```

Note that is is possible for more than one of your dates to be tied for the max date.  In this case, the order of your `WHEN` clauses determines which one wins.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the reply..everything fine with your code but I can't do GROUP BY RefNumber..Can you please check once ..Thanks

Comment: @user3583912, if there are 2 rows with the same `RefNumber`, how do you pick the date & action to return?

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH cte AS (
  -- Build table of date 
  SELECT [RefNumber], 
         [ActionDate]= [FirstVisitedDate], 
         [Action] = 'First Visited' 
  FROM [Table1] 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [RefNumber], 
         [SecondVisitedDate],  
         'Second Visited' 
  FROM [Table1] 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [RefNumber], 
         [RecoveryDate], 
         'Recover'
  FROM [Table1]
), cte2 AS (
  -- Add row_number to pull most recent to top
  SELECT  [RefNumber],
          [Action],
          [ActionDate],
          [DateRank] = 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RefNumber 
                                 ORDER BY [ActionDate] DESC)
  FROM [cte]
)
-- select only the most recent
SELECT * 
FROM cte2 
WHERE [DateRank] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The brute force approach isn't so bad with four columns:

```
select (case when FirstVisitedDate >= SecondVisitedDate and
                  FirstVisitedDate >= RecoveryDate and
                  FirstVisitedDate >= ActionDate
             then FirstVisitedDate
             when SecondVisitedDate >= RecoveryDate and
                  SecondVisitedDate >= ActionDate
             then SecondVisitedDate 
             when RecoveryDate >= ActionDate
             then RecoveryDate
             else ActionDate
        end),
       (case when FirstVisitedDate >= SecondVisitedDate and
                  FirstVisitedDate >= RecoveryDate and
                  FirstVisitedDate >= ActionDate
             then 'FirstVisitedDate'
             when SecondVisitedDate >= RecoveryDate and
                  SecondVisitedDate >= ActionDate
             then 'SecondVisitedDate'
             when RecoveryDate >= ActionDate
             then 'RecoveryDate'
             else 'ActionDate'
        end)     
from table t;
```

EDIT:

Doing this in a `group by` is just a question of adding aggregation functions:

```
select RefNumber,
       (case when max(FirstVisitedDate) >= max(SecondVisitedDate) and
                  max(FirstVisitedDate) >= max(RecoveryDate) and
                  max(FirstVisitedDate) >= max(ActionDate)
             then max(FirstVisitedDate
             when max(SecondVisitedDate) >= max(RecoveryDate) and
                  max(SecondVisitedDate) >= max(ActionDate)
             then max(SecondVisitedDate) 
             when max(RecoveryDate) >= max(ActionDate)
             then max(RecoveryDate)
             else max(ActionDate)
        end),
       (case when max(FirstVisitedDate) >= max(SecondVisitedDate) and
                  max(FirstVisitedDate) >= max(RecoveryDate) and
                  max(FirstVisitedDate) >= max(ActionDate)
             then 'FirstVisitedDate'
             when max(SecondVisitedDate) >= max(RecoveryDate) and
                  max(SecondVisitedDate) >= max(ActionDate)
             then 'SecondVisitedDate'
             when max(RecoveryDate) >= max(ActionDate)
             then 'RecoveryDate'
             else 'ActionDate'
        end)     
from table t
group by RefNumber;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, Thanks for the reply. But I got 9 date columns to get Maxdate..Above is just for sample..Thanks

Comment: @user3583912 . . . The logic isn't that much harder for nine columns, just a lot of copy and pasting.  But it does emphasize how useful the `greatest()` and `least()` functions are in other databases.

Comment: I will do that..yes your right those are useful functions in Mysql

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RecordID, MaxDate
FROM SourceTable
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(d) MaxDate 
                FROM (VALUES (date1), (date2), (date3), 
                             (date4), (date5), (date6), 
                             (date7)) AS dates(d)) md
```

Comment: That is amazing -- having used CROSS APPLY for a few different things, but never seen that syntax with Values before, worked for me perfectly when doing 5+ mod dates to lookup. 
However, It doesn't address the Action returned as well specified in the Q though
For peoples [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), this has been around in sql since 2008